# Событие click срабатывает лишь один раз

Tags: jquery, регулярные-выражения, click

Вот такой код:

```
    jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
    var matchParams = match[3].split(','),
        validLabels = /^(data|css):/,
        attr = {
            method: matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ? 
                        matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
            property: matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels,'')
        },
        regexFlags = 'ig',
        regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''), regexFlags);
    return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
}

$ (document).ready(function(){


    $('body').on( "click", 'a:regex(href,^tmswin:)', function(e) 
    {
        e.preventDefault(); //отменяем переход по ссылке
        var href = $(e.target).attr('href');
        var modal_url = href.substring(7);
        //if(_post_data===undefined)
        var _post_data={};
        //if(_opts===undefined) 
        var _opts={};
        $('body').TMSWin($('body'),{url:modal_url,post_data:_post_data,opts:_opts});
        //return true;
    });


});
```

Срабатывает только первый раз, потом не срабатывает

Comment: Удалите `g` из `regexFlags = 'ig'`, если вы используете `RegExp#test` использование этого модификатора нежелательно.

Comment: Удалил. Не помогает

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, но он ж там все равно каждый раз новый объект RegExp создавал, поэтому `g` вряд ли бы влиял на что-нибудь

Comment: @Grundy Это best practice, не ответ. Я прекрасно вижу последовательность строк кода, и вижу, что не влияет.

Comment: Попробовал вместо кастомного поставить $('body').on( "click", 'a[href^="tmswin:"]', function(e) Результат тот же. то есть не в регекспе дело.

Comment: Приведите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Судя по всему, приведенный код работает именно так как и ожидается: http://jsfiddle.net/z48370re/

Comment: Полностью пример не могу привести ибо много кода. Но суть в том что даже если не будет аяксить данные с сервера и потом создавать модальное окно то все равно один раз то есть дело не в том коде по событию

Comment: @AntonKuzmenko, ничего не понятно. По ссылке выше ты можешь найти свой код, в котором обработчик click срабатывает каждый раз. Если у тебя не срабатывает значит либо у тебя другой код, либо проблема в совсем ином месте. В любом случае в текущей редакции вопрос стоит закрыть либо как не воспроизводится, либо как не хватает примера воспроизводящего ошибку. Отредактируй вопрос так, чтобы ошибка воспроизводилась. Для правки можно использовать кнопку [edit].